# In F#, how to update/replace a nested record using a list index?

Tags: f#

(Totally Newbie).

Please assume the following in F#

```
module Visit =
    type Model =
        {  Name: string }
                   
module Cell =
    type Model =
       {  Visit: Visit.Model option  }

module Column =
    type Model =
        {  AppointmentCount: int
           InnerRows: Cell.Model list } 

module App = 
 ...stuff with List.tryFind to return an open column ...

  let AddVisit (c:Column.Model, v:Visit)  =
                { c with c.InnerRows[AppointmentCount] = { c.InnerRows[AppointmentCount] with Visit = v } }
```

Assuming there will be 4 cells per column, the Visit is supplied by a database read, and the column instance is found through a couple of List.tryFind's, can a nested record (i.e., the visit of a cell) be replaced/updated with the AppointmentCount as an index?

That is, this fails:

```
let AddVisit (c:Column.Model, v:Visit)  =
            { c with c.InnerRows[AppointmentCount] = { c.InnerRows[AppointmentCount] with Visit = v } }
```

*Error: Field bindings must have the form 'id = expr,'*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take for instance a newly created record.

```
let myRecord2 = { MyRecord.X = 1; MyRecord.Y = 2; MyRecord.Z = 3 }
```

To update only two fields in that record you can use the copy and update record expression:

```
let myRecord3 = { myRecord2 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

[Copy and Update Record Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions)

Comment: Sorry...How would an index into a nested record be written?

Answer (score 0):

```
let AddVisit (c:Column.Model, v:Visit)  =
            { c.InnerRows.[c.AppointmentCount]  with Visit = Some v }
```

Note that c.InnerRows.[c.AppointmentCount] specifies a specific cell.model to which the Visit will be set. (Also, the "." in front of the [ allows for direct indexing into the list.